# HTML5 video element not requesting end Range

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-headers, http-range

I have a `<video>` and `<audio>` element which load a file (mp4, mp3, doesn't matter) from my server via Range requests.

It seems however that the element only request the end Range from my server, and from there on out tries to stream directly from bytes 0 to the end, causing the player to be stuck in a "download loop", which makes the browser suspend all other actions until the download is complete.

[image: Range request 1]

[image: Range request 2]

Does anyone know a solution to this issue? Do I for example have to make my stream request HAVE an actual end to its `content length` or `accept-ranges`?

Here's the full request list from Chrome and at the bottom you can see that a request for the url `view?watch=v__AAAAAA673pxX` just stays pending, basically until either a new request is placed by the `element`.

[image: Full range request history]

In a nutshell: html5 elements get stuck in a download loop when using `http-range` requests and cause all other requests to stay "pending".

**UPDATE**

The issue was resolved server-side.

Whereas the original stream function would literally output every byte, I've modified the code to output ONLY the size of the actual buffer. This forces the `elements` to make a new request for the remaining data.

An important note here is to return the `content-length`, `accept-ranges` and `content-ranges` that match the file's size, start and ending position in each `HTTP RANGE` request.

For future references:

```
function stream(){
    $i = $this->start;
    set_time_limit(0);
    while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
        $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
        if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
        }
        $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
        $i += $bytesToRead;
    }
}
```

new stream function:

```
function stream()
{
    //added a time limit for safe-guarding
    set_time_limit(3);
    echo fread($this->stream, $this->offset);
    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a video of 1M bytes 
When you browser request for video the first time it will send headers like this

```
Host:localhost
Range:bytes=0-
```

Range header `bytes=0-` means browser is asking server to return till whatever it can return ie. no end position is specified

To this server would usually reply with whole file except last byte to preserve the range context

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:99999
Content-Range:bytes 0-99999/1000000
```

Now suppose your video is downloaded till 30%  and you seek to 70% then browser will request that part header would be like this

```
Host:localhost
Range:bytes=700000-
```

> It seems however that the element only request the end Range from my server,

You can see you inferred wrongly it's the starting position of video part

Now server might reply like

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:300000
Content-Range:bytes 700000-99999/1000000
```

Note `Content-Range` it explicitly tells what portion of file .So my guess it that your server is not sending this information and browser is getting bugged.
Also sometimes mime-types can also cause problems try to use the exact mimetype of your file like `Content-Type: video/mp4`.If you use `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` then might cause compression which would disabled range headers

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately the code that was provided used a `while` loop to output data to the request. I've made it so that ONLY the buffer size is outputted (for example (1024 * 1024)), so that the output stream would be closed as soon as the buffer size was reached. 

This ensured that the `<video>`/`<audio>` HAD to make a new request for data because the data provided did not match the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Any update for this issue? I see Chrome and Firefox sent Range without right end, and server writes the whole file in response. The proposed solution with explicit buffer works but it looks like a hack